# How do inline for loops interact with print?

Tags: for-loop, perl, foreach

Here's a reprex:

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
my @array = ("word1", "word2"); 
print foreach @array, "\n";
```

The effect is to print `word1word2\n`. How is this line of code actually parsed by the Perl interpreter?

I think I understand what `print foreach @array;` would do. My understanding is that this is an inline loop that is essentially equivalent to the following `foreach` block:

```
foreach @array {
    print; # i.e. print $_; 
}
```

However, it's very unclear to me why appending `"\n"` to this gives valid code. I've tried parenthesizing the expression in different ways, but they led to errors.

Comment: A `foreach` takes a list, so `"\n"` is added to the elements of the `@array` to make the list that is handed to `foreach`, so to speak.  So `foreach` iterates over `$array[0], $array[1] ... $array[-1], "\n"`.  Is that all you are asking?

Comment: This is "postfix" notation ("statement modifier"), see [it in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Compound-Statements).  See [foreach in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Foreach-Loops)

Comment: In case the behavior of ```print``` itself is part of your question, the other thing to mention is that ```print``` takes a list, so ```print @array, "\n"``` prints all the elements of ```@array``` and then the ```"\n"```. You could picture that postfix notation of ```foreach``` as ```foreach``` feeding a list to ```print```; that "list" incudes the ```"\n"```, as others have explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the `foreach` [statement modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers).

Here's what happens:

1. The expression after the foreach (`@array, "\n"`) is evaluated in list context.
2. For every scalar produced,

   1. `$_` is aliased to that scalar.
   2. The expression before the `foreach` (`print`) is evaluated.

This is similar to following:

```perl
foreach ( @array, "\n" ) {
   print;
}
```

However, in the statement modifier version, there's no scope created, and one can't use `next`, `last` or `redo` to affect the looping.